# Jittering when moving mouse

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have an opengl program and I am using SDL for the window creating / event handling etc. Now, when I move the mouse to re-position the cameras yaw/pitch, I get a jittering image, with the old position flashing on the screen for a split second.

Now i think this may be an issue with the way I re-position the mouse. I have it set back to the center of the screen at the end of the re-positioning. Here is the said code:

```
void handleMouseMove(int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    GLfloat vertMouseSensitivity  = 10.0f;
    GLfloat horizMouseSensitivity = 10.0f;

    int horizMovement = mouseX - midWindowX;
    int vertMovement  = mouseY - midWindowY;

    camXRot += vertMovement / vertMouseSensitivity;
    camYRot += horizMovement / horizMouseSensitivity;

    if (camXRot < -90.0f)
    {
        camXRot = -90.0f;
    }

    if (camXRot > 90.0f)
    {
        camXRot = 90.0f;
    }

    if (camYRot < -180.0f)
    {
        camYRot += 360.0f;
    }

    if (camYRot > 180.0f)
    {
        camYRot -= 360.0f;
    }

    // Reset the mouse to center of screen
    SDL_WarpMouse(midWindowX, midWindowY);
}
```

Now, Inside my main while loop, here is the SDL code for calling this function:

```
while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                if( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
                {
                    Game.running = false;
                }
            }
            if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION )
            {
                int mouse_x, mouse_y;
                SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x, &mouse_y);

                handleMouseMove(mouse_x, mouse_y);
            }
```

I found that getting the coordinates like this verses `event.motion.x` and `event.motion.x` caused less of this effect.

Any thoughts on how I could avoid this 'jittering' image?

Comment: is the surface you are drawing to double buffered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `SDL_WarpMouse`, another mouse move event is generated that you are handling again. You must ignore the second one.

To make things more complicated, it's not like every motion event is followed by one in the opposite direction caused by `SDL_WarpMouse`. The events may come for example two motions and 1 generated by warp to the middle of the screen. I have written this code which works for me:

```
void motion(SDL_MouseMotionEvent *mme)
{
    static bool initializing = true;  // For the first time
    static int warpMotionX = 0, warpMotionY = 0;  // accumulated warp motion
    if (initializing)
    {
        if (mme->x == midWindowX && mme->y == midWindowY)
            initializing = false;
        else
            SDL_WarpMouse(midWindowX, midWindowY);
    }
    else if (mme->xrel != -warpMotionX || mme->yrel != -warpMotionY)
    {
        /****** Mouse moved by mme->xrel and mme->yrel ******/
        warpMotionX += mme->xrel;
        warpMotionY += mme->yrel;
        SDL_WarpMouse(midWindowX, midWindowY);
    }
    else    // if event motion was negative of accumulated previous moves,
            // then it is generated by SDL_WarpMotion
        warpMotionX = warpMotionY = 0;
}

void processEvents()
{
    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        switch (e.type)
        {
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                motion(&e.motion);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, I myself am interested in `-mme->yrel` than `mme->yrel` and that's why it's in the original code I have it negated wherever I use it (I removed it in the code I posted above)

Where I wrote `/****** Mouse moved by mme->xrel and mme->yrel ******/` is where you want to act on the mouse motion. Other code is to ignore motion generated by `SDL_WarpMouse`

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: When I add `handleMouseMove(mme->xrel, mme->yrel);` in replace of your comment, the instant I move the mouse, it points directly up, and get stuck there.. any thoughts?

Comment: Your handleMouseMove gets absolute mouse positions. xrel and yrel are motion of the mouse, which means how much the mouse has moved.

Comment: ah, ofcorse. Ok, I got that working, however it did not have any effect on the jitter :/. I'll make you correct however, as you have targeted my problem. thanks!

Comment: The jitter must be something else then! :-? I can't really tell without seeing the code, but are you by any chance drawing after each event handling or handle all then draw once?

Comment: Nope, just at the end of the loop. If I adjust the controls to look using keys, there is no problem. Just happens with mouse motion.

Comment: hmmm... are you sure this has nothing to do with double buffer? You are redrawing before each swap right? To make sure, make it single buffer and see if the jitter goes away

Comment: I had this issue with using WarpMouse and getting a jittery mouse even after attempting to just skip the next mouse motion event with a flag. I finally corrected it by just only processing one mouse motion event per tick. Perhaps this is unacceptable if you're making a precise first person camera, but for my cursor based game this worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is the only relevant question on SO, and as far as I could tell, the only answer anywhere online. I noticed that there's no SDL_WarpMouse function mentioned in the docs, but there is an SDL_WarpMouseInWindow function. I'm an SDL newbie so I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if the API changed at some point?