# How to get (true) mouse displacement with windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm wondering how to get true mouse displacement with windows.

For example, I could save the position of a previous mouse position, and request the new position, and subtract the latter from the previous. But this would not give me true mouse displacement.

Imagine the previous cursor position would be the maximum x coordinate of your screen resolution, and the user is moving his mouse to the right. Is there still a way to capture the true mouse displacement then?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you mean by "mouse displacement". Do you mean the physical movement of the mouse on the desk? No, you don't know that because the computer doesn't know that. Moving the mouse moves a cursor on the screen. All you can determine is how far the cursor has moved on the screen. It won't move anywhere at all if it's all the way to the right, and you move the physical mouse further to the right on the desk.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I mean the physical displacement of the mouse on the desk, or something similar. There MUST be a way, take a look at first person shooters pc games for example: they don't rely on the position of the mouse on the screen to rotate the camera, only on true mouse displacement

Comment: There might be a way to do it using DirectInput (although as I understand it, this is not recommended for a mouse). Generally, Windows handles translating the movement of the mouse to movement of the cursor, and all your application needs to worry about is the position of the cursor on the screen. It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @CodyGray The problem I'm trying to solve is creating a first person shooter camera. If you ever played one of those, you would understand that in such a virtual world, the 'cursor' (for aiming) always stays in the middle of the screen. However, the camera must rotate when the user moves the mouse.

Comment: @Serodis: That tracks the movement of the *cursor*, not the movement of the physical mouse device. See my initial comment (and xcrypt's reply) for a discussion of the difference.

Comment: A common trick is to move the cursor back to the center of the screen so after reading the current position so it will never hit the edges.

Comment: You might be able to get this done using relative displacement with RawInput: http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/raw_input.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is not possible to track physical mouse displacement with the Windows API. However, DirectInput provides features to keep track of it. You can also 'fake' it using only the Windows API, using the neat little trick in the answer of SO user DXM

Comment: Downvoted because it is possible using pure Windows API when using WM_INPUT message.

Answer (score 2):

Although it might be possible to actually read sensor data (after all the mouse itself only reports movement, not location), I'm not aware of how this could be done. I think at the very low levels of windows, that displacement information gets translated into cursor position on the screen and from then on, you will always be limited by your screen resolution.

In whatever you are trying to do, is the mouse cursor still visible?

A little while ago, I wrote a WPF numeric edit box control that mimicked the way those controls work in Expression Blend. The ones where you can drag the mouse from the edit box itself and it'll change the value.  I ran into exactly same issue that you found and my solution was to hide the mouse cursor, detect displacement on every tick and reset the cursor to the center of the screen.  Then when the user lets go of the button to stop dragging, I would put the cursor back to where I found it before the drag.  This worked out really well and Expression Blend also behaves this way in hiding the cursor.

Comment: No the mouse cursor is not visible in whatever I am trying to do :) That would work well, I'll try it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know DirectX has its own APIs to interact with peripherals, that is recommended for game developers. You should look into it - try for example [DirectX 8 and the Mouse](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/directx-and-xna/directx-8-and-the-mouse-r1657), more detailed documentation you can find [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842(v=vs.85).aspx specifically: "The use of DirectInput for **keyboard and mouse input is not recommended**. You should use Windows messages instead"

Comment: For which reasons it is not reccomended I don't know, but for unreccomended feature seems to have suprisingly lot of support-look for example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinput8.idirectinput8.createdevice%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Seems that it is the only way to get it done anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way is to use window hooks. Here is a minimalist sample using C(++)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    int ScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN); 
    int ScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int x = hookStruct->pt.x * ScreenWidth / 65536);
    int y = hookStruct->pt.y * ScreenHeight / 65536);
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

HHOOK LowLevelMouseProcHook = NULL;

void hook_window_procedure()
{
    if (LowLevelMouseProcHook == NULL)
        LowLevelMouseProcHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)LowLevelMouseProc, (HINSTANCE)NULL, NULL);    
}

void unhook_window_procedure()
{
    if (LowLevelMouseProcHook != NULL)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(LowLevelMouseProcHook);     
}
```

You can hook the mouse calling `hook_window_procedure();` and unhook it by calling `unhook_window_procedure();`

You will receive calls to `void LowLevelMouseProc(...)` whenever the mouse moves. `lParam` contains a pointer to `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` and you find all needed mouse information in its structs. Most interesting here is `POINT pt;` that is in relative screen coordinates assuming 1/65536th of the screen. Transform them to real pixels by multiplying with `int ScreenWidth` or `int ScreenHeight` and dividing by 65536

If you struggle being clamped by the screen borders, you can make a workaround setting the mouse back to the center of your window each call. This is often seen in older games. If you are not forced to use only the Windows API, I would try using Direct Input.

Another way would be to evaluate `WM_INPUT` directly in your WindowProc for example. This reads data directly from the Human Interface Device (HID) stack and should have raw Mouse-Data in it. Here is a link to the [MS-Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#WM_INPUT)

Answer (score 1):

The method on windows is as such:

```
// you can #include <hidusage.h> for these defines
#ifndef HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC
#define HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC         ((USHORT) 0x01)
#endif
#ifndef HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE        ((USHORT) 0x02)
#endif

RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];
Rid[0].usUsagePage = HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC; 
Rid[0].usUsage = HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE; 
Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;   
Rid[0].hwndTarget = hWnd;
RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0]));
```

then in message loop:

```
case WM_INPUT: 
{
    UINT dwSize = sizeof(RAWINPUT);
    static BYTE lpb[sizeof(RAWINPUT)];

    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE) 
    {
        int xPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastX;
        int yPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastY;
    } 
    break;
}
```

Installing hooks will trigger sensitive antiviruses.
[MSDN doc to refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/taking-advantage-of-high-dpi-mouse-movement)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of displacement ? : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus

Try  pitch/yaw  : [How could simply calling Pitch() and Yaw() cause the camera to eventually Roll()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784445/how-could-simply-calling-pitch-and-yaw-cause-the-camera-to-eventually-roll)

FPS style : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/game-programming/94944-mouse-input-aiming-fps-style-using-glut.html

and this  : [Jittering when moving mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286875/jittering-when-moving-mouse)

pseudo code:

```
int mouseX, mouseY;     
int oldMouseX, oldMouseY;

while(game_is_Running)
{
    oldMouseX = mouseX;
    oldMouseY = mouseY;

    mouseX = get_new_mouse_from_windows_X();
    mouseY = get_new_mouse_from_windows_Y();

    if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) > 0) 
    {
       // mouse moved to the right
    }

    else if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) < 0) 
    {
        // mouse moved to the left
    }



    if ((mouseY - oldMouseY) < 0)
    {
        // mouse moved  down 


    }

    else if ((mouseY - oldMouseY) > 0)   
    {
        // mouse moved    up  


    }

}
```

Comment: No, he doesn't mean this kind;)

Comment: @Scott McIntyre This is not the displacement I am talking about. The problem here is that the cursor might be stuck on one of the utter bounds of the screen, and if the user still wants to move his mouse in that direction, nothing will happen. Also, I know how the maths work :)

Answer (score 0):

A common method for this (in games):

Every frame of the game, get the position of the mouse and then recenter the mouse in the middle of the window using operating system functions. For every frame other than the first, this should give you an accurate displacement information. The key is to just be re-centering the mouse every frame so it never reaches the blocking outer bounds of the screen.

EDIT: Woops, didn't realize that DXM had already said this.